# Getting only data out of HTML page in python

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

Im working on a project for which I need the content of an HTML page given ts url.

Im doing something like this

```
con=urllib.request.urlopen(url)
a=con.read()
con.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(a)


print(soup.get_text())
```

But the problem is Im getting all the java script , and other things as well. I just need the displayed content of a webpage. Any pointers on how to go about it?

Comment: `Im getting all the java script`, if the page contents are being loaded via ajax, `BeautifulSoup` wont help you much. Else, try reading only the `<body>` tag.

Comment: If you need to have JS runned, use [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) to fetch the website

Comment: Or selenium, to stay in python